# Knex.js SQL syntax error near 'select'

Tags: postgresql, coffeescript, knex.js

I'm getting an odd error:

```
{ __cid: '__cid9',
  method: 'insert',
  options: undefined,
  bindings: 
   [ 500,
     'Dinner',
     '10/02/2015 7:57 PM',
     '09/29/2015 8:00 PM',
     'Grand Plaza',
     1 ],
  sql: 'insert into "expense" ("amount", "description", "due_date", "payment_date", "vendor_id") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, select "vendor_id" from "vendor" where "name" = $5 limit $6)',
  returning: undefined }
error: syntax error at or near "select"
at [object Object].Connection.parseE (/.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:534:11)
  at [object Object].Connection.parseMessage (/.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:361:17)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

I have run the raw SQL with those value cut and paste and it works just fine.

This is the code thats generating the error:

```
Promise.each subbudget.expenses, (expense) ->
    vendor.get(expense.vendor).then (vendor_id) ->
        knex('expense').insert(
            due_date: expense.dueDate
            vendor_id: (knex.first("vendor_id").from("vendor").where({name: vendor_id}))
            amount: expense.amount
            description: expense.description
            payment_date: expense.paidDate
        )
```

Edit (Partial Solution):
The issue seems to be parentheses missing around the SELECT statement. Knex offers .wrap(), which only works on raw, and .as(), which only works on nested statements; for some reason this does not qualify as a nested statement, so I can't get parentheses around it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

knex.raw("(" + knex.first("vendor_id").from("vendor").where({name: vendor_id}).toString() + ")")

Not the cleanest, but use .toString(), then wrap it in .raw()